# How to properly setup a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have added a `UIPageViewController` to my project for creating a walkthrough screen, but I can seem to understand how to make this to work using storyboards.

First I have defined the two data source methods: `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController`.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(WalktroughScreenPageViewController *)viewController index];

    if (index == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(WalktroughScreenPageViewController *)viewController index];


    index++;

    if (index == 3) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}

- (WalktroughScreenPageViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    WalktroughScreenPageViewController *childViewController = [[WalktroughScreenPageViewController alloc] init];
    childViewController.index = index;

    return childViewController;

}
```

Also for showing the dots at the bottom I added this two methods:

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
```

What I can understand it's how to do the setup in `ViewDidLoad`. I tried something like this which gives me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataSource = self;

    WalktroughScreenPageViewController *ic = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    [self setViewControllers:@[ic] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Can someone point me to the right direction ?

Comment: Have you looked at the Page-Based Application template in Xcode? I use the code from that template as boilerplate code for setting up a page view controller in storyboard. The template loads the page view controller as a child view controller.

Comment: Hmm, haven't thought of that. I will look at it.